# ASP.net ajax submit button with textBox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, web

what is wrong of my code when i click button i can not read the textbox value from server side part
my code as follow:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="c-form">
<asp:Label ID="zr_message" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox style="margin:0px;float:left;" ID="zr_tb_hotel_name" runat="server"  placeholder="Hotel Prand Name"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="zr_tb_hotel_name"            
        ErrorMessage="Hotel Brand Name Field is empty</br>" 
        style="margin:0px;clear:both;display:block;color:Red;"/>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox style="margin:0px;float:left;" ID="zr_tb_hotel_location" runat="server" placeholder="Hotel Location"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="zr_tb_hotel_location"            
            ErrorMessage="Hotel Location Field is empty</br>" 
            style="margin:0px;clear:both;display:block;color:Red;"/>
</div>
<div>        
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclientclick="GetServerDate();return false;" />
    <button id="back" type="reset">Cancel</button>
</div>
</form>

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        x_ref = Request.QueryString("ref")

        If (String.Equals(x_ref, "hotel")) Then
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
                GetServerDate()

        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub GetServerDate()`enter code here`
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "Data =" + zr_tb_hotel_location.Text)
        Response.End()
    End Sub
enter code here
```

Comment: Private Sub GetServerDate()
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "Data =" + zr_tb_hotel_location.Text)
        Response.End()
    End Sub

Comment: I don't use this method of ajax, not I can be wrong, but if you write method on Server side, they don't know the Exact value at time of post, hence it will give View state value to you which in this case is blank. I suggest you learn Jquery, this method is too slow for real time processing anyways.

Comment: Do you have jquery example ?

Comment: jQuery("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function(){ jQuery("#result").html(jQuery(this).val()}); something like that will work.

Comment: i found solution i used Scriptmanager